# search binary tree linear function

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to do a little program, which takes a search binary tree.

Calculate for each node:

- two function function L(u) and R(u)
- where L(u) is the sum of the keys of the nodes in the left subtree rooted in u
- and R(u) is the sum for the right subtree.

The program should have as output:

- the key nodes that satisfy this property L(u)* k < R(u)
- printed in ascending order of key, where k is an integer in input.

The problem is that the function must have a linear complexity, and I can't make her less than n^2.

someone can help me?

Comment: What is the language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to calculate sum of keys in a subtree. It's a well-known problem.

```
func calc(node):
   if node is null:
       return 0
   node.lval = calc(node.left) # L(u)
   node.rval = calc(node.right) # R(u)
   return node.key + node.lval + node.rval
```

Where `lval` and `rval` initialized to 0 first.

Now you have to walk down the tree (first left, than right) and check condition.

```
func print(node):
   if has left child:
       print(node.left)
   if node.lval*k < node.rval:
       output node.key
   if has right child:
       print(node.right)
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, as it seems pretty much correct. As a minor point, you don't need the `if there are no children` part - it's redundant.

Comment: @ami-tavory thanks, you're right. Fixed.